# How to Load Cypher File into Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have generated a cypher file and want to load it into neo4j.

The only relevant documentation I could find was about loading csv's.

I also tried the shell but it seems to have no effect

```
cypher-shell.bat -uneo4j -pne04j < db.cql
```

Copy paste into localhost:7474/browser makes the browser unresponsive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the current Neo4j version you can use [Cypher Shell](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/cypher-shell/) to achieve your goal.

From the docs, [Invoke Cypher Shell with a Cypher script from the command line](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/cypher-shell/#cypher-shell-syntax):

```
$ cat db.cql | bin/cypher-shell -u yourneo4juser -p yourpassword
```

Note that this example is based in a Linux instalation. If you are using Neo4j with Windows, you will need to adjust this command to your needs.

Comment: While I tried this already and the question has this noted from the beginning, this is the right way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: Very important is to have semicolon at the end of queries. I didn't have it didn't works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when this has been added but in the current version (4.4) an alternative way to load a cypher file to NEO4J (GUI) is by dragging and dropping the cypher file over the web browser, which then offers two options, either to add it to the favorites or to paste it in the editor.