# There is no have neo4j-shell.bat for Neo4j CE 3.1.3?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to import CSV data to Neo4j following guide from: https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/#_importing_the_data_using_cypher.

I already exported CSV from relational database MSSQL and created nodes/relations with Cypher at Neo4j browser successfully.

However, when I try to use `neo4j-shell` to execute Cypher code as below:

```
bin/neo4j-shell -path adventure.db -file cypher/import.cypher
```

I didn't find the `neo4j-shell.bat` in my folder. There's just a `cypher-shell.bat`, but no `neo4j-shell.bat`?

Although I could execute CQL by `cypher-shell.bat`, but it just runs the code step by step.
I want to execute the whole Cypher script with one command through command line.

How could I achieve this goal?

I search some samples, but almost using `neo4j-shell.bat` to work.
I have no idea why I didn't have neo4j-shell.bat. I'm using Neo4j CE 3.1.3.

Comment: Hi @Ken! Did my answer help you solve your problem? If so, can you [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark? This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this Neo4j Knowledge Base post](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/using-neo4j-shell-neo4j-ce-3x/), from Neo4j 3.0 access to neo4j-shell is no longer possible from the desktop-installers for Windows and OSX.

In the current Neo4j version you can use [Cypher Shell](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/cypher-shell/) to achieve your goal.

From the docs, [Invoke Cypher Shell with a Cypher script from the command line](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/cypher-shell/#cypher-shell-syntax):

```
$ cat adventure.db | bin/cypher-shell -u yourneo4juser -p yourpassword
```

Note that this example is based in a Linux instalation. If you are using Neo4j with Windows, you will need to adjust this command to your needs.

This answer was adapted from my [previous answer in a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43656719/6835358).